# Processing a for loop statement to parse value from a provided text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in python and I have been practicing parsing strings using the "dictionary" and "for" statement. For some reason, I am not sure how the code is calculating "tree" and "node" values.

Python 3 Code

```
words = {'cad' : 2345}
tree = {}
for word, frequency in words.items():
    node = tree
    for ch in word:
        if ch not in node:
            node[ch] = {}
        node = node[ch]
    node[f'${word}'] = frequency
```

Results

```
node
{'$cad': 2345}
tree
{'c': {'a': {'d': {'$cad': 2345}}}}
```

I am not sure how did "tree" get that value, when I had defined "tree" only in the start equal to "node".

Thanks

Comment: Consider adding the expected result for your given example (cad: 2345).
Also: Check your wording, most of your questions does not make much sense (`...who tree...`, `...which the code is...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that line 4 of your code `node = tree` you assign the variable name node to the variable tree.  If you thought you were making a new copy of tree assigned to node, you are mistaken.  The variable node simply points to the variable tree, so changes made to node are in reality being made to tree.